# Where can I read more about the fields of the transaction returned by listtransactions API

Tags: json-rpc, documentation, listtransactions

I am looking at the results returned by [listtransactions API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list) and I do not understand the difference between blocktime, time and timereceived. Help tells me the following:

> "blocktime": xxx,         (numeric) The block time in seconds since epoch (1 Jan 1970 GMT).
>
> "time": xxx,              (numeric) The transaction time in seconds since epoch (midnight Jan 1 1970 GMT).
>
> "timereceived": xxx,      (numeric) The time received in seconds since epoch (midnight Jan 1 1970 GMT). Available for 'send' and
> 'receive' category of transactions.

Can anyone explain these fields in a little bit more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitcoin developer reference has a section on the [listtransactions](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listtransactions) call:

The `blocktime` is the timestamp of the block that confirmed this transaction on your local best blockchain. It is not returned for unconfirmed transactions.

The `time` field tracks the time that your wallet started tracking this transaction.

The `timereceived` field tracks the time that your node learned about the transaction, or alternatively the time of the block that included this transaction.